# How to switch between tabs and directly show pushed view controller?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, xcode7, pushviewcontroller

This is my code:

```
  VideoDetailViewController *VideoDetailVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VideoDetailViewController"];

  UINavigationController * navigationController = (UINavigationController *) [[self tabBarController] selectedViewController];

  [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];

  [navigationController pushViewController:VideoDetailVC animated:YES];
```

I am writing this code in tabbar's second index. I want to directly go to the Video Detail screen, which is child view controller of tabbar's zero index.  Everything works fine but what I see is: it shows a parent view controller which is tabbar's zero index. After a second it pushes to the Video Detail screen. I just don't want to show the zero index. What is the solution? Help will be appreciated.

EDITED:

```
#import "TWPhotoCollectionViewCell.h"

@implementation TWPhotoCollectionViewCell

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        self.imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        self.imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.imageView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
    [super setSelected:selected];

    self.imageView.layer.borderWidth = selected ? 2 : 0;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace below line

```
  [navigationController pushViewController:VideoDetailVC animated:YES];
```

With

```
  [navigationController pushViewController:VideoDetailVC animated:NO];
```

It may solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate :)

Comment: one more question. I don't want to create another thread. How to determine in custom cell class if the cell is created first time? I mean if the cell index is zero, how the custom class can know this? I have used UICollectionView for choosing videos in cideopickerview class. By default I want to set selected video at zero index. How can you help?

Comment: I tried to take a variable  to check but I don't know where to inititialize its value.

Comment: Not getting your question

Comment: I am using custom cell class and here I want to know if the cell is being created first time. i.e cell at zero index. I want to use this condition in custom class. check out my edited question. I have put custom cell code there.

Comment: setSelected method only calls when user select any cell. But I want to get first cell selected by default. I don't know how to do this

Comment: you can take instance variable of type bool and can set as `YES` in `initWithFrame` method. Because `initWithFrame` called everytime. So, first time also

Comment: So you can put if else in initwithframe. initialy your bool flag should be set to NO. then check in if statement that if it is no then call `setSelected` method and set your flag to YES. So, second time it will execute else part which does nothing.

Comment: I tried this one. after cell is created first time, I change BOOL variable to YES. But during creation of second cell BOOL variable reset to NO again. I declared BOOL variable in .h file. And this code in initWithFrame method:  if(isOldCell == NO)
        {
            self.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2;
        }
        isOldCell = YES;

Comment: Then perform this thing in current viewcontroller in which your collection view is loaded. use `cellForItemAtIndexPath` to check bool. i.e. whatever you have done in `initwithframe` now do in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

Comment: I cannot do that. Because cellForItemAtIndexPath will call multiple times. And I only want zero index selected at initial time.

Comment: put if else. like if (status == NO) { //this is firsttime and set status = YES} so it is execute very first time then it will execute else block

Comment: I already tried that before. It worked. I put condition that if cell index is zero, I set true to setSelected. But zero cell will be highlighted even after I will select other cells because of this condition. I hope you get it.

Comment: oh yeah. It was so easy. let me try with this one

Comment: just completed it. Even after tweaking in cellForItemAtIndexPath, I had to tweak in didSelect method as well to get the zeroth cell and unselect it. Thanks for your time and help. Cheers

Comment: How to preserve icon color in UITabbar? I don't want to subclass UITabbarController. I never did and I think its a tiredsome job. So any easy way to display original icon color in tabbar?

Comment: `[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];`, you should ask separate questions instead of asking different question in comment!!